# Transparent Login through URL containing Username & Password - Possible?

Tags: authentication, login

Is it possible to create a URL, containing the domain, username and password, to login to a Sharepoint website, much like is possible with vanilla HTTP authentication?

I have tried a URL in the following format:

```
https://[domain]\[username]:[password]@server.com/default.aspx
```

The purpose here is to allow us to pass a user's detail from one website to another.

Comment: Is this an intranet or extranet scenario, i.e. are users domain users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint supports Basic HTTP authentication. The issue is that certain modern browsers don't support the specified URL format for security reasons (admittedly I have only confirmed this with IE so any input on other browsers would be useful).

See [Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) for more info on IE specifically.

The complexity of your problem really depends on:

1. Whether multiple authentication providers / user stores are in play and,
2. Location of users (i.e. internal/domain or external)

If everyone is internal and authenticated against the same user directory (e.g. AD), then you can just use Windows authentication and benefit from a form of "single sign on".

If everyone has an internal domain account but is accessing the system from outside the network, you can use a reverse proxy server (such as ISA server or TMG) to provide a "SSO" cookie that allows cross-site access from a forms based login (again this assumes all apps use the same user directory). Both of these reverse proxy servers can delegate Basic authentication if required.

If however your applications maintain separate user directories, some form of credential caching may be necessary in order to provide "SSO", as others have suggested.

In all cases, if you are using Basic auth you should make certain that you secure the channel using SSL as credentials are not encrypted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sharepoint installation and the network in which it resides are outside of my control. Users are not located within the same network/domain as the Sharepoint install. My whole solution was intended to work around what is, truly, an abysmal attempt to configuring Sharepoint and then forcing everyone to use it.
I will have to investigate the browser security aspect - it is really the only avenue I have sufficient access to in order to hack around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure [SSO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262932%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that the SP2010 equivalent is the Secure Store Service: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806889.aspx